# How to copy contents of Intellij Quick Fixes to the clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

For a Quick Fix / Intention popup, as the following:

[image]

How can that text

> TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

be copied to the clipboard?  I can not "select" the text and then command[/ctl]-C it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> copies the tooltip text to the clipboard.